# Use Liquibase with Play Java Framework

Tags: java, playframework, liquibase

I'm trying to use Liquibase with Play Framework. I think my problem is I'm trying with Play **Java** framework, not Play *Scala*.

This is the plugin I'm trying to make it work: https://github.com/Ticketfly/play-liquibase
It could be another option but I can't change my project to Scala.

This is my stacktrace and why I think my problem is that I'm not using Scala.

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[NoSuchMethodError: play.api.Logger.info(Lscala/Function0;)V]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:190)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:124)
    at play.core.server.ssl.ServerSSLEngine$.createSSLEngineProvider(ServerSSLEngine.scala:29)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$7.apply(AkkaHttpServer.scala:126)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$7.apply(AkkaHttpServer.scala:124)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.<init>(AkkaHttpServer.scala:124)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServerProvider.createServer(AkkaHttpServer.scala:445)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServerProvider.createServer(AkkaHttpServer.scala:443)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:222)
```

So, how can I use Liquibase with Play Java Framework?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you have a dependency conflict. That `NoSuchMethodError` usually means you have the same dependency pulled in twice, one which calls some method and the actual resolved class which does not have it.

Answer (score 0):

So, @dan-w was right. I had a dependency conflict. What I've done to solve it was download plugin source code and change Scala version to 2.6.0 in every case.

So in `build.sbt` I have:

```
def playVersion(scalaVersion: String) = CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion) match {
  case Some((2, scalaMajor)) if scalaMajor == 12 => "2.6.0"
  case _                                         => "2.6.0"
}
```

Used `sbt> publishLocal` and used my own version.